# How to decrease the radius between a sphere centerpoint and a point P and find the new coordinates of point P?

Tags: math, trigonometry, spherical-coordinate

I got a point (p) rotating around another point (c) with a known constant radius (r). I also know the position of the two points at all time.

I would like to decrease the distance (r) between the two points, from lets say from 11 to 7. How can I define the new point (p) coordinates after decreasing the distance?

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is more about computer languages than about pure math problems. Perhaps you could write a program in <your-fav-language-here> and tag it as such? Then we could offer help. But as it stands, your question is not appropriate. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: Hi Rajah,
Thanks for the notification. I will try to work it in a Python example and update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple formula:
c+(p-c)*ScalingFactor